# Problems with clients for secondary dns server

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

Good evening! Im trying to make a high availability environment on my work, in order to do that I setup a little lab installing 2 servers; one with WS 2008 R2 and the other with WS 2012 R2 (same as real environment but virtuals). The domain controllers and dns was installed successfully on both and replicates without problems

1. Server 1 (primary), WS 2008 R2, IP=172.16.200.10/24, dns primary=172.16.200.20, secondary=loopback
2. Server 2 (secondary), WS 2012 R2, IP=172.16.200.20/24, dns primary=172.16.200.10, secondary=loopback

I did not use AD integrated dns zone, instead primary/secondary zones were configured. The problem comes with clients, if I make a query to primary dns work well, when primary is shutdown I have no response from secondary even after a long wait, `ipconfig /flushdns` does not work either nor rebooting. Am I doing some bad configuration?

I get a good response with commands `repadmin /showrepl` and `dcdiag /test:dns /dnsbasic`, it seems like no errors were found. Funny thing is when I use Linux i got a response from secondary dns server.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `1.` Why did you choose to not make the zones AD integrated? That's the most common configuration. `2.` Each DC should use it's own ip address as secondary DNS and should use loopback (127.0.0.1) as tertiary DNS. `3.` Are the clients configured to use both servers for DNS?

Comment: `when primary is shutdown I have no response from secondary even after a long wait` - Can you explain the exact problem in more detail?

Comment: If you scan the secondary, is it listening on port 53?  Can you connect to it with nslookup ("server 172.16.200.20") ?

Comment: Sorry, it was too late for edit.

@joequerty: I did not made the first configuration on the server, it was already there so I dont have the permission to touch anything yet. Yes, clients are configurated with both servers, been `.10` primary. My problem is the secondary dns does not give any answer in windows clients, shutting down first one (.10) and using `nslookup` for test. This is the answer it gives when both are alive `default server: ws2k8ad.domain.lan address: 172.16.200.10` and after i shutdown that server just throws a timeout. How do I test dns without nslookup?

Comment: In this scenario, nslookup isn't the right tool. Nslookup only uses the default (primary) DNS server. It will not failover to the secondary or tertiary DNS server. Are you having specific AD/DNS problems when the primary DC/DNS server is down?

Comment: Im really not sure, the only test i know is `nslookup` so far. But it does work on linux machines, not sure why windows dns are slow with this. Is there another way to check or make a query to secondary dns? Or how can ensure secondary dns service is working properly? Thank you.

Comment: You can force nslookup to use the DNS server you migth need, either typing `nslookup anycomputer yourDNSserver`, or interactive:
`nslookup`     
`server yourDNSserver`
Sure this doesn't serve as a failback test, but at least you'll find if your clients can have an answer from your secondary DNS server.

Comment: By the way, not really sure about this (and cannot find documentation to confirm or discard) but Powershell command `Resolve-DnsName` should fall back to the secondary DNS server.

Comment: Hello curropar! Than was a great help men.

From my test client I finally reached secondary dns query :)

In cmd: `nslookup` (time out message)

`>server 172.16.200.20` (another timeout but this time show .20 as default server)  `>set type=ns` `>domain.lan` (name of my zone) `domain.lan... (showing all servers)`

Thank you! How can I mark your response as an answer?

Comment: Glad to help! That was just a comment, let me add it as an answer, and then you'll be able to mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force nslookup to use the DNS server you migth need, either typing:

`nslookup anycomputer yourDNSserver`

Or interactive:

`nslookup 
server yourDNSserver
anycomputer`

Sure this doesn't serve as a failback test, but at least you'll find if your clients can have an answer from your secondary DNS server.

By the way, not really sure about this (and cannot find documentation to confirm or discard) but Powershell command `Resolve-DnsName` should fall back to the secondary DNS server. As per my tests, this is true, but again, I cannot find documentation.

Answer (score 0):

windows built-in nslookup does not "ever" use the secondary DNS IP configuration to look up (but it actually works - if you ping the hostname it will show you the IP).

I found it the hard way, only after I installed BIND which comes its own version of nslookup - it comes back with the IP address of the hostname and shows that the secondary DNS server provided the information. Try BIND's nslookup.